# Why I should use anonymous function to stored my function as variable

Tags: javascript, function, callback

why this code run perfectly

```
function remember(number) {
    return function() {
        return number;
    }
}

const returnedFunction = remember(5);

console.log( returnedFunction() );
// 5
```

but this code give me error

```
function remember(number) {
        return number;
}

const returnedFunction = remember(5);

console.log( returnedFunction() );
// returnedFunction is not a function
```

Comment: Because in your second code, `returnedFunction` is the `number` you returned, not a function

Comment: *"why i should use anonymous function to stored my function as variable"* [What are Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, your function `remember` returns another function, which you then you can execute. In the second example, your function `remember` returns a number. That's why `returnedFunction()` runs fine in the first case, but throws an error in the second.

Comment: when I do this 

function remember(number) {
        return number;
    }

console.log( remember(5) );

//5
its work, but when I add variable like this

function remember(number) {
        return number;
}

const returnedFunction = remember(5);

console.log( returnedFunction() );

 it doesn't work why?